# Filter visitorLogger used in filter mapping URL - *.xhtml not found

Tags: java, maven, undertow, wildfly-12

I have module of application which is running in WildFly 12 application server. 
I can compile it and build without any problems, but when I'm trying to deploy it I have following problem

```
14:19:42,528 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myapp: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myapp: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010050: Filter visitorLogger used in filter mapping URL - *.xhtml not found
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.1.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.1.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.1.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.1.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: What does your filter configuration look like?

Comment: I've solve this problem. There was a bug in WildFly 12. I need to update the Jandex module to version 2.0.5.